# Must a compiler always remove a try-catch block if it's proven to be non-throwing

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, exception, try-catch

Consider this:

```
#include <stdexcept>

template <class T>
void F(T &&t) {
    try {
        t(); 
    } catch(...) {}
}

int main() {
    F([]() noexcept {});             // Call 1
    F([]{});                         // Call 2
    F([]{ throw std::exception{}; });// Call 3
}
```

I found on `clang++-6.0` with flags `-std=c++17`, regardless of the optimization flags I gave, there is always no `__gxx_personality` and any exception handling code for `Call 1`.

Can such optimization be relied on when using a different compiler? I only consider `C++11` and above.

Comment: @ Fureeish Can you make that an answer?

Comment: Done. See the answer below

Comment: @Fureeish Thank you, I have finally understood ```noexcept```.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu: I feel there is a slight difference between the title and the body of the question. "Can such (a) optimization be relied on?" implies that the title should have been "**Must** a compiler always remove a try-catch block if it's proven to be non-throwing?"

Comment: @MSalters The title is clarified, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`noexcept` specifier was added to c++11 as a replacement for `throw()`. It guarantees that the function *will not throw*. The difference between it and `throw()` is that with `noexcept`, if the function *actually throws*, the stack **only maybe gets unwinded**, which was not the case with the former one (stack always gets unwinded). This enables more optimizations, such as completely omitting the exception handling.

To summarize, it's up to compiler when it decides to omit the exception handling, but with `noexcept` it has *no reason to not do so*, which was really hard to determinate in other case.